# Where and how to install provisioning profile in Visual Studio for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, urbanairship.com, p12, mobileprovision

I have implemented push notification using UrbanAirship. I am not getting notification. I have google for it and it says I need to install certificates. I got 2 certificates.

> 1- appidentifier.p12
>
> 2- appidentifierIOS.mobileprovision

I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017(Enterprise Edition). I connect simulator of Mac System remotely. Now I know `appidentifier.p12` will be installed in Mac System. But I don't know where and how to install `appidentifierIOS.mobileprovision`. I think I need to install in Visual Studio but don't know how to install.

**Specification:**

```
Windows 10

Visual Studio 2017(Enterprise Edition)

Xamarin.Forms
```

Can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial : [Production Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/publishing-to-the-app-store/profiles#production-provisioning-profile) ,refer to step 6.

> Drag it into the Xcode Organizer or double-click it to install. The profile will then appear in the Xcode Organizer

and than config it as below

[image]